# Display loading while using Observable with Async pipe in template

Tags: angular, ionic2, observable, angularfire2

Situation: I am using FirebaseObjectObservable to populate my Ionic 2 (rc0) template. 
Template code:

```
<ion-card-content>
  <p>{{(course | async)?.description}}</p>
  <br>
  <h2>Learning Objectives</h2>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor = "let objective of (course | async)?.objectives">{{objective.text}}</li>
  </ul>
  <h2>Takeaway</h2>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor = "let takeaway of (course | async)?.takeaways">{{takeaway.text}}</li>
  </ul>
</ion-card-content>
```

TS code:

```
this.course = this.af.database.object('/bbwLocations/courses/' + courseId);
```

this.course is a Firebase Object Observable. Everything works! But whenever I come into the template, there is a flash of empty no data. Then all the data jump out! Very not UX friendly. So I want to use some kind of pre-loading strategy. But since there is not TS logic here. Everything is controlled in template level with async pipe. How would I add loading in this situation?

Comment: Route resolver is a convenient way to handle view prerequisites.

Comment: What do you mean Router resolver? I am in Ionic 2 RC0. There is no router I believe.

Comment: I don't use Ionic, but at least this is achievable with A2 router https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#resolve-guard I'm not aware of how good I2 plays with A2 router. Anyway, the best way to treat it is to resolve the dependency before component initialization (e.g. before `nav.push` call if you use it for navigation).

Answer (score 17):

Maybe a little late but in case someone else is wondering how to manage this...
What about using a template?

you could for example use something like:

```
<ion-card-content *ngIf='(course$ | async) as course; else loading'>
  <p>{{course.description}}</p>
  <br>
  <h2>Learning Objectives</h2>
  <ul>
     <li *ngFor = "let objective of course.objectives"> 
         {{objective.text}}</li>
  </ul>
  <h2>Takeaway</h2>
  <ul>
     <li *ngFor = "let takeaway of course.takeaways"> 
         {{takeaway.text}}</li>
  </ul>
</ion-card-content>

<ng-template #loading>
  Loading stuff...
</ng-template>
```

so your ion-card-content will be hidden, showing the #template, until the async pipe is loaded.

Answer (score 12):

You could do something like this:

```
<style>
  pre {
   color: orange;
   // or whatever you want
  }
</style>
<ion-card-content>
  <p>{{(course | async)?.description}}</p>
  <br>
  <h2>Learning Objectives</h2>
  <pre *ngIf="!(course | async)">loading objectives...</pre>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor = "let objective of (course | async)?.objectives">{{objective.text}}</li>
  </ul>
  <h2>Takeaway</h2>
  <pre *ngIf="!(course | async)">loading takeaways...</pre>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor = "let takeaway of (course | async)?.takeaways">{{takeaway.text}}</li>
  </ul>
</ion-card-content>
```

Comment: This works. But if I want exit animation, like fade out the loader when ngIf become false. I won't be able to do that. Also, is that possible to tap into the observable and use Ionic Loader component for this?

Comment: If you want to use **ngIf** I believe [`Animations`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/animations.html) are the way to go. You could use **ngClass** instead of **ngIf** and do animations/transitions with CSS. `transition: 1s opacity 0.5s linear`, and such...

Comment: Could you update your solution and give me an example how to easily use animations to do a fadeout of the pre element? Thank you!

Comment: But this make lots of unecessary requests... :(

Comment: If it's duplicating your request: you are giving observers access to a cold observable. You should use `share()` or similar to setup `course` as a hot observable. `this.course = this.httpClient.get('whatever').pipe(shareReplay(1))`. this will store the most recent result, so that if you have multiple subscribers: they can observe a replay of the result instead of initiating a new HTTP request.

Answer (score 4):

Lets say we have an observable **meals$**. We need to show loader when the observable is getting resolved(i.e fetching data).
Below is the solution.

```
<div *ngIf="meal$ | async as meal; else loading;" >
   //use the meal variable to show some data
</div>
<ng-template #loading>
   //Show your loader here
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with using `ngIf="course$|async";else loading` is that when the observable resolves to a falsy value like `0 or false` we are stuck with the loader screen.

Inorder to bypass this problem, you can think about using custom pipes which are more robust

**Step 1** :
Create a `loading.pipe.ts` file

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core"
import { Observable, isObservable, of } from "rxjs"
import { map, startWith, catchError } from "rxjs/operators"

@Pipe({
  name: "loading",
})
export class LoadingPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform<T>(val: Observable<T>): Observable<{loading:boolean,value:T,error:unknown}> {
    return isObservable(val)
      ? val.pipe(
          map((value: any) => ({ loading: false, value })),
          startWith({ loading: true }),
          catchError((error) => of({ loading: false, error }))
        )
      : val
  }
}
```

**Step 2**: Register the pipe in the declarations array in your `*.module.ts` file

```
import { LoadingPipe } from "./loading.pipe"

@NgModule({
  declarations: [LoadingPipe,…],
  imports: [...],
  exports: [...],
})
export class SharedComponentsModule {}
```

**Step 3**: Usage in component file `*.component.ts`

```
<ng-container *ngIf="course$ | loading | async as course">
 <div *ngIf="course?.value">
  display my resolved values...
 </div>
 <div *ngIf="course?.error">
   Error!
 </div>
 <div *ngIf="course?.loading">
   my loader component...
 </div>
</ng-container>
```

Reference and credits
[Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/pipes-custom-data-trans)
[Async loading pipe](https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/angular-show-loading-indicator-when-obs-async-is-not-yet-resolved-9d8e5497dd8)